# Failed to determine a suitable driver class error in Spring application

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

My Spring app works just fine in IDE (IntelliJ IDEA), but throws an error when I try to run JAR file. The error: `ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class`

My application.propreties part, related to database:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.zimovit'
version = '0.8.0'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task myFatJar(type: Jar){
    manifest{
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.zimovit.SpringGusliBot.SpringGusliBotApplication'
    }
    baseName = 'gusli-bot-jar'
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from{configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect {it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}}
    with jar
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation group: 'org.telegram', name: 'telegrambots-spring-boot-starter', version: '5.7.1'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I've tried to change application.propreties file (commented out lines), as some related articles advice, but it did not work at all. Tried different versions of java - doesn't work either. Also I tried to exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration using `@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` annotation, this changed the error, and with this annotation the app doesn't run even in IDE. I also tried to add `implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jdbc', version: '5.3.24' dependency in build.gradle. I think, maybe a have to add some other dependency or there is some mistake in myFatJar task, but I couldn't find a way to fix it so far.

I've tried Shadow and Ktor plugins to build fatJar, but the error remains. I still think that the problem is in the way I build the fatJar, since the app works in IDE. Maybe I missed something crucial.

Comment: you can refer: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa, this will help to clear the confusion you have related to properties setting.

Comment: I've tried settings in different variations, but it did not work. As I see, there's no need to refer driver explicitly, and I've commented out that string in properties, but the result is the same - the app works and interacts with DB in IDE, but throws the same error when I try to run in from jar. I think there may be some problem  in the way how I build fatJar, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I've defined application.properties file location explicitly with @PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties") annotation in main class and now it works.